# Use CDN and HTTPS for Spree::Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Is it possible to use a CDN like Amazon Cloudfront with spree?  I know I can set `config.action_controller.asset_host` in `production.rb`, but this doesn't affect the `Spree::Image`, or any spree helper functions like `product_image()`.

Also, the `/admin/image_settings/edit` url with setting for `s3_protocol`, which seems to have no effect, even setting it to blank.  I would like to be protocol agnostic, and have the URLs formed like `//foo.cloudfront.com`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spree's image uploader is provided the [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem.  There's a handy guide for [Using Cloudfront with Paperclip](http://blog.tristanmedia.com/2009/09/using-amazons-cloudfront-with-rails-and-paperclip/).  Paperclip will not use asset_host.

The first step would be to get your S3 image hosting working the way you want, and then get it to work through Cloudfront.

s3_protocol being '' should use protocol relative URL's as shown in [this pull request](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/849).

Comment: I don't understand where these settings would be placed though, since Spree provides a special Paperclip config?

Comment: You can provide your own paperclip initializer which should be able to override some of the values that spree provides.

Comment: Seems you might be able to override the settings with a `Spree::Image` decorator as well.